# Is it possible to insert an image usin the same source of another one?

Tags: html

I have an HTML page.

Inside the HTML page, there is an image with an URL source generated dynamically using an Oracle database. (This something we don't have the privileges to change)

We would like to insert other images inside the same page using the same URL source.

Is that possible to please using only HTML?

```
<!-- Image generated by our framework. The URL is dynamic -->
<img src="URL\xxxxxxxx.jpg" id="Image1">

<!-- New image we would like to add -->
<img src="Same as Image 1" id="Image2>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cloud storage the image locally, preload an image with JavaScript then calling the image or calling the same image url and changing the img ID as you have it.

Example of preloading on js file:

```
function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more how to do that please ?

Comment: I’am sorry I miss understood what you were asking no you can not insert other images inside the same page using the same url source. That not how it works, the url points to the image file and if you don’t have access to that database that image won’t change.